# Upgrade additional Team Foundation instance(s)?

Tags: tfs, upgrade

Can I confirm that if I already have a functioning TFS 2015 server and I want to upgrade an existing TFS 2010 server - I need to backup any existing collection DBs, *reinstall* TFS with upgrade of new instance and then restore/attach existing collection DBs?

In other words, there doesn't seem to be support for adding extra collection DB's from an older version? (e.g. like a SharePoint Content DB attach).

TFS upgrade guide is here: http://vsarupgradeguide.codeplex.com/releases and suggests a reinstall for Migration Path upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

The process is described at [When upgrading from TFS 2008 or TFS 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Work/customize/upgrade-tfs-2008-or-2010).

Shortly, there is no direct path from 2010 to 2015, so you need to upgrade your collection to 2012 or 2013 (I recommend the latter).

In your case I would:

1. Backup, backup and make sure backup can be restored
2. Prepare a new TFS 2013 instance in a VM -- you may share the SQL instance if you are careful
3. Detach from TFS the 2010 collection you want to move
4. Copy the detached collection database to the SQL instance supporting TFS 2013 (you can use a full backup copy-only)
5. Attach the collection database on TFS 2013, the upgrade process starts asynchronously
6. Adjust the Process Templates etc. as described in the article
7. Detach the collection, now upgraded to 2013
8. Copy the detached collection database to the SQL instance supporting TFS 2015
9. Attach the collection database on TFS 2015, the upgrade process starts asynchronously
10. Adjust the Process Templates etc. as described in the article

I my experience the TFS detach and attach operations are generally safe, but may fail (e.g. 2012u2 attach was buggy); that is why I recommend backup with tested restore procedure.

Update:
In addition to Rangers' guidance, you may find useful SSW [Rules to Better TFS 2015 Migration](https://rules.ssw.com.au/rules-to-better-tfs-2015-migration).

Comment: Excellent! I will also try to use the tool.

Answer (score 1):

What you do is simply detach the collection though the TFS admin console, then backup & restore, then attach it to TFS 2015. The attach process will then do the upgrade on that collection. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936138%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

Comment: Ahh ok, seems I have to detach the collection from 2010 first - then maybe 2015 will be able to detect it. I'll give it a try out-of-hours, thanks.

Comment: Yes this catches some people, it won't show up when you try and attach the collection unless it has been detached previously!